# django_heroku package isn't working with Django app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

I need to configure my Django app to pull the heroku config vars (The DATABASE_URL and SECRET_KEY) to get the database to work with it.

I look at the [docs for django_heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration) which said to put this at the bottom of the settings.py file after installing the package:

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I entered all that in and ran the server and got this error message:
[image]

I unfortunately can't understand this error message enough to get the relevant information to fix this problem.  Would you know how I can fix this so I can't get my Django app to work with the database in Heroku?

Any assistance with this problem will be much appreciated!

Comment: I just checked the link - it actually says to put the `import` statement at the *top* of the file (which is where import statements usually should go). Does this fix the error? (I'm not certain, I've never used this package - I have deployed Django projects to Heroku but I've always just used config vars for sensitive details and whitenoise for staticfiles.)

Comment: I tried importing it at the top as well to no avail.   This is the only method of concealing sensitive information that I can find on Heroku's website (if i'm not mistaken.)  If there are other ways of doing it I would like to know.   Thanks.

Comment: It's simple enough to hide the sensitive connection details, just use Heroku "config variables" for them (which are what Heroku calls environment variables), then use [`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) in your settings to get hold of them, without having the values in your code. But this package, which I've never heard of, sounds really convenient for all deployment issues, so I'd be curious to know why the steps you're directed to take aren't working!

Comment: Trying to do it the way you suggested I entered this in settings.py: DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL').  After running the server from there I got a 500 server error in the browser.  Am I close?

Comment: you either need to provide a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable on your local machine, or give a default value to use if its not found (which is what the second parameter to `os.getenv` is). In the latter case you still have to hardcode it, but usually you're not bothered about giving away the connection details to your database on localhost :)